# There exists infinitely many primes formed of 2^(F[n!+1])-1

Tags: prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, big-numbers, mersenne-numbers

I have a conjecture:

> **Ultra-Primes-Conjecture**.
>   There exists infinitely many primes formed of $2^{F[n!+1]}-1$.

Here $2^p-1$ is Mersenne number, $F[n+2]=F[n+1]+F[n], 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...$ is Fibonacci number, $n!$ is the factorial function.

$n! + 1$ is prime for (sequence A002981 in the OEIS): $$n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 27, 37, 41, 73, 77, 116, 154, 320, 340, 399, 427, 872, 1477, 6380, 26951, 110059, 150209, ...$$
These are $2,3,7,39916801,...$.

Indices of prime Fibonacci numbers are:
$$3, 4, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23, 29, 43, 47, 83, 131, 137, 359, 431, 433, 449, 509, 569, 571, 2971, 4723, 5387, 9311, 9677, 14431, 25561, 30757, 35999, 37511, 50833, 81839, 104911, 130021, 148091, 201107, 397379, 433781, 590041, 593689, 604711, 931517, 1049897, 1285607, 1636007, 1803059, 1968721, 2904353, 3244369, 3340367,...$$

So $2^{F[2!+1]}-1 = 3, 2^{F[3!+1]}-1= 2^{13}-1= 8191$ are the only two known Ultra-Primes! I guess after $3$, $8191$ there are more prime heros formed of $2^{F[n!+1]}-1$.

And more, Ultra-Primes increase very quickly, they can completely compare with Graham's Number and TREE(3)

Comment: It is not known whether or not there are infinitely many Mersenne primes, nor is it known whether or not there are infinitely many prime Fibonacci numbers, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_prime) for example.

Comment: Apparently, you do not have any idea how big Graham's number and TREE(3) are. With a reasonable input $n$, you will come nowhere close to Graham's number, not alone TREE(3)

Comment: But it is right that the sequence grows very quickly, so I would much more expect finite many such primes, I would even expect only "a handful".

Comment: @Peter , I guess  infinitely many  such primes

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D0X9DYRLmTNY&ved=2ahUKEwjnmofTjMfnAhXD1FkKHXkFBjwQwqsBMAB6BAgEEAQ&usg=AOvVaw1WwuS-Nju3wQo3fb6RYXsx

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently known whether there are infinitely many *Ultra-Primes*. Indeed, we don't even know if there are infinitely many Mersenne primes.

A proof or disproof of your conjecture is out of reach with currently available tools in number theory.

Comment: If there are only finite many Mersenne primes or finite many Fibonacci primes or finite many primes formed of n!+1, then Ultra-Primes would be only two or three...so, my Ultra-Primes-Conjecture is powerful

Comment: I think there exists Inertia Law and Polar Method for integer sequences. But I can not express them clear!

Comment: @aboy If you like my answer you can mark it as "Soved"